# Name decoration in C

Tags: c, standards, name-decoration

Does any standard mandate name decoration?

As far as I know most (all?) conforming implementations add underscore prefix to the name of each exported symbol. Is this guaranteed by a C, POSIX or some other standard?

Comment: The term you are looking for is [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: No, only few implementations do that. For example, almost all ELF-based targets don't add an underscore to symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a "standard" but the prepended underscore seems to be a very common convention dating from the 1970s. From [What is the reason function names are prefixed with an underscore by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908568/):

> At the time that UNIX was rewritten in C in about 1974, its authors
>   already had extensive assember language libraries, and it was easier
>   to mangle the names of new C and C-compatible code than to go back and
>   fix all the existing code.

It is required for C names if you want to interoperate with the Microsoft compilers on Windows (win32 only; win64 does not use decoration since it has only a single standard calling convention).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names

See also: [Why do C compilers prepend underscores to external names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627511/why-do-c-compilers-prepend-underscores-to-external-names)