# Will the functions and variables precede with an "_" when compiled using gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system, kernel

I am learning OS development in a Linux environment using GCC. I learnt in Bran's Kernel Development that all the functions and variable names in C when compiled precedes with an "_"(underscore) in its corresponding Assembly source file.
But when I went through the assembly source of a compiled C program, I can't even find the "_main" function.
I performed the following.

cpp sample.c sample.i

gcc -S sample.I

Comment: You compile user-space program. How "kernel" tag relates with that problem?

Comment: Use more recent resources for recent tools/software

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was true in the early days. A given C function `foo` would show up as `_foo` in the assembler. This was done to avoid conflicts with hand generated `.s` files.

It would also be limited to 8 characters total [a linker restriction].

This hasn't been true for decades. Now, symbols are no longer prefixed with `_` and can be much longer than 8 characters.

---

**UPDATE:**

> So, Nowadays GCC does not produce a _ in front of functions and variables?

For the most part, no. IMO, the reference you're citing, on this point, does seem to be a bit dated.

Most POSIX systems (e.g. linux, *BSD) use `gcc` [or `clang`] and they leave off the `_`.

When I first started programming in C [circa 1981], the `_` was still being used. This was on AT&T Unix v7, System III, and System V.

IIRC, it was gone by the early 1990s for newer systems (like linux). Personally, I haven't encountered the `_` prefix since then, but I've [mostly] used linux [and sometimes cygwin].

Some AT&T Unix derived systems may have kept it around for backward compatibility, but, eventually, most everybody standardized on "foo is foo". I don't have access to OSX, so I can't rule out Johnathan's comment regarding that.

The `_` had been around since the early days of Unix (circa 1970). This was before my time, but, IIRC, Unix was originally written in assembler. It was converted to C. The `_` was to demarcate functions either written in C, or asm ones that could be called from C functions.

Those that didn't have the prefix were "asm only" [as they may have used non-standard calling conventions]. Back in the day, everything was precious: RAM, CPU cycles, etc.

So, asm functions could/would use "tricks" to conserve resources. Several asm functions could work as a group because they knew about one another.

If a given asm function could be called from C, the `_` prefixed symbol was the C compatible "wrapper" for it [that did extra save/restore in the prolog/epilog].

> So, I can just call the main function of a C program as "call main" instead of "call _main"?

That's a reasonably safe bet.

If you're calling a given function from C, it will automatically do the right thing (i.e. add prefix or not).

It's only when trying to call a C function from hand generated assembler that the issue *might* even come up.

So, for asm, I'd just do the simple thing and do `call main`. It will work on most [if not all] systems.

If you wanted to "bullet proof" your code, you *could* run your asm through the C preprocessor (via a `.S` file) and do (e.g.):

```
#ifdef C_USES_UNDERSCORE
#define CF(_x)          _##_x
#else
#define CF(_x)          _x
#endif

    call    CF(main)
```

But, I think that's overkill.

It also illustrates the whole problem with the `_` prefix thing. On a modern system [with lots of memory and CPU cycles], why should an assembler function have to know whether an ABI compatible function it is calling was generated from C or hand written assembler?

Comment: It depends on platform, at least.  On Mac OS X, if I compile a C source file `any_function.c` containing the function `any_function()`, the object file contains a symbol `_any_function` according to `nm -g any_function.o`.

Comment: So, Nowadays GCC does not produce a _ in front of functions and variables ri8?

Comment: So, I can just call the main function of a C program as "call main" instead of "call _main" ri8?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm stunned. The `_` prefix was always a pain to deal with and [back in the day] I was overjoyed to see it dropped [circa introduction of ELF, etc.] Still, OSX has always had some similar quirks. Does `objdump` report the same? Does it depend on `.o` format (e.g. COFF, ELF, or whatever OSX uses)?

Comment: `objdump any_function.o` generates `-bash: objdump: command not found` :)  — on Mac OS X.  Yes, Mac OS X goes about things its own way, and it doesn't use COFF or ELF (the file type is `Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sigh. I had forgotten that OSX was a FreeBSD [and cocoa(?)] layer over Mach. And, IIRC, before moving to x86, they were trying to preserve PowerPC [and mc60000] binary compatibility. `Mach-O` is OSX's (nee Mach's) "answer" to ELF, rather than just adopting ELF. IMO, a prime example of NIH. They could probably just make `_main` a symbol alias of `main` but I'm guessing that `Mach-O` probably doesn't support symbol aliases :)

Comment: The `otool -tv any_function.o` generates output starting:
`any_function.o:` / 
`(__TEXT,__text) section` /
`_any_function:` /
`0000000000000000 testl %edi, %edi`.  (Comment not completed for over almost two hours.)

Answer (score 3):

As detailed by Craig, it's a convention that modern formats/ABIs like COFF and ELF don't follow anymore.

On some targets, that use different ABIs, it's still in use.
Examples are NeXT/OS X's [Mach-O](http://Mach-O) or 16- and 32-bit Windows. 64-bit Windows doesn't use the underscore anymore (although GCC continued doing so for a time, till 4.5.1 specifically).

Additionally, the underscore might appear as part of a bigger prefix. For example `__imp_` in `__declspec(dllimport)` symbols or `_Z` in the Itanium ABI.

If you for some reason, need to influence the mangling, GCC provides a [`-f[no]leading-underscore`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) flag. This will break ABI-compatiblity.

---

Some links:

- [Calling conventions
  for different C++ compilers and operating systems](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) By Agner Fog
- [Why do C compilers prepend underscores to external names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627511/why-do-c-compilers-prepend-underscores-to-external-names)
- [The history of calling conventions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040102-00/?p=41213) By Raymond Chen
- [x86 Calling Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) on Wikipedia