# Dll injection cant load a function address

Tags: c, dll, hook, dll-injection

Im trying to hook the keyboard with a dll injection in C.
When i try GetProcAddress on  the KeyboardProc function the GetProcAddress return NULL and GetLastError returns error 131.
after that I get a DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.
In windows website it says:

```
ERROR_NEGATIVE_SEEK
131 (0x83)
An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.
```

I dont understand what is the problem in my code.

The injector I am using:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR) "dll.dll");
    if (dll == NULL)
    {
        printf("The DLL could not be found.\n");
        FreeLibrary(dll);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("The DLL was found.\n");
    HOOKPROC addr = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll, "KeyboardProc");
    if (addr == NULL)
    {
        printf("The function was not found.\n");
        FreeLibrary(dll);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("The function was  found.\n");
    HHOOK handle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, addr, dll, 0);
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        printf("The KEYBOARD could not be hooked.\n");
        FreeLibrary(dll);
    }

    printf("Program successfully hooked.\nPress enter to unhook the function and stop the program.\n");
    getchar();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(handle);
    FreeLibrary(dll);

    return 0;
}
```

The dll Im using:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved)
{

    switch (Reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(0, (LPCSTR) "DLL attach function called.", (LPCSTR) "Dll injection", MB_OK);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        MessageBox(0, (LPCSTR) "DLL detach function called.", (LPCSTR) "Dll injection", MB_OK);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(0, (LPCSTR) "DLL thread attach function called.", (LPCSTR) "Dll injection", MB_OK);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        MessageBox(0, (LPCSTR) "DLL thread detach function called..", (LPCSTR) "Dll injection", MB_OK);

        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    FILE *LOG;
    LOG = fopen("LOG.txt", "a+");
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        fputs((char *)lParam, LOG);
        fclose(LOG);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Im using win10 and mingw.
Both injector and dll are compiled as C.

Comment: Is your DLL compiled as C or C++?  It makes a difference.

Comment: Missing `extern "C"`. Without it name mangling kicks in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is simple:

```cpp
extern __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

Most probably is defined in `cpp` file and as a result it is C++ function. C++ to allow function overloading is using [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), so your function is visible under a name which is result of mangling.

You have to force it to be a `C` function so name mangling is disabled.

So add `extern "C"` or make source to have `C` specific extension (compile it as C code). Your code is pure `C`.

Comment: My code is written in c and compiled as a c program, so it will not fix my error.

Comment: then try add underscore in front https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627511/1387438

Comment: do you mean _KeyboardProc? And where do i need to change the name(dll or injector)?

Comment: In the injector.