# c++ - Read external char object symbol line by line

Tags: c++, char, embedded-resource

I'm writing a program in OpenGL, and I wanted to compile the shader file into the executable directly, so the user can't ruin the program (by deleting the shader file or editing it) without knowing what he's doing.

I compiled the shader into an object file with:

```
ld -r -b binary -o basic_shader.o res/shaders/Basic.gl
```

And I got these symbols:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
00000000000000e5 g       *ABS*  0000000000000000 _binary_res_shaders_Basic_gl_size
00000000000000e5 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_res_shaders_Basic_gl_end
0000000000000000 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_res_shaders_Basic_gl_start
```

I already created a class for managing shaders. But the constructor is supposed to get as a param, the shader file path, to open it and read it.

So is it possible to read the symbol `_binary_res_shaders_Basic_gl_start` (which is a `char[]`) line by line ?

Comment: You are aware that reading in that text cannot reproduce the shader, aren't you?

Comment: Why ? Before I implemented the "read file" stuff, I was writing the shaders into strings directly. But now I've changed the thing a little bit, so I can't do same.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible for a user here (e.g. me) to copy that text and recreate your shader? Isn't it obvious that the shader consists of more than the sizes of the different parts?

Comment: I meant is there a way of reading a char string (e.g. `foo`) line by line ? That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Please show what you have coded and what is missing/failing/misbehaving.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689410/how-to-compile-all-resources-into-one-executable-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479691/is-there-any-standard-way-of-embedding-resources-into-linux-executable-image

Comment: What is wrong with strings for shader code in C++ code? Btw. I do this a little bit different: writing shaders in separate files but translate them into C++ code (strings) and compile them with the rest. For this, I'm using something like described here: [SO: How to include data object files (images, etc.) in program and access the symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47415163/7478597).

Comment: @Scheff But I want to embed the file into the executable directly, your solution is using `ofstream` so external files, and that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I "translate" the shader files to a C++ file which contains the original file contents as const string variable definition. Then I compile this generated C++ file with the rest of C++ sources. Needless to say that all this pre-processing is managed automatically in our build chain.

Comment: Um it's okey, but won't it be good too, to implement the shaders into the executable ? That's what I'm asking for