# Combine resources into single binary

Tags: c, linux, bash, packaging, software-packaging

I have a program:

```
dist/
├── myapp
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── launcher
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── libmyapp.so
│   └── share
│       ├── data00.zip
│       └── data01.zip
```

What I want to do is combine all of that into a single executable file, so that, for the end user, it's a single file to copy around.

I'd be OK with a bash shell file too.  Also, I have control over the .so file.  I could statically link it to the player.

How do I combine all of this into a single / merged executable file?

This is on linux.  The .zip files are opened with `fopen()`.  I'm hoping for some kind of magic involving something like FUSE or similar technology.

I was hoping to avoid embedding the .zip as a DATA segment payload or using a .h file because that would change my program in ways that I didn't intend.  This is more of a packaging question.

Comment: For which platform?

Comment: how are zip files used?

Comment: zip files are loaded using API commands like fopen to find the .zip in the /share folder.  The code looks for `pwd` and then goes up and over to `share/` to find the .zip files

Comment: I ran across this https://makeself.io/ and it seems solve part of the problem -- possibly enough of the problem. It extracts the binary into a temp folder.  A better solution would be no extraction.

Comment: you can convert your zips into C headers and use it in your code; for example with: `xxd -i data00.zip > mydata00.h`

Comment: This is the true duplicate that _properly_ answers the question: [Is there a Linux equivalent of Windows' "resource files"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997172/is-there-a-linux-equivalent-of-windows-resource-files)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an unusual need or question. And there are a number of different ways to do this.

On Windows, of course, you should use a Windows Resource with the Windows Resource Compiler.
But you are on Linux :O)

On Linux, `objcopy(1)` is what comes to the rescue. There is an old Linux Journal article specifically about this:

- [Embedding a File in an Executable, aka Hello World, Version 5967](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967)

It really does not get simpler than that.

BTW, there are quite a few questions on SO that deal with the same thing, all using a variation of the same answer. For example: [Is there any standard way of embedding resources into Linux executable image? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479691/is-there-any-standard-way-of-embedding-resources-into-linux-executable-image)

The top answer uses the assembler to do the same thing that `objcopy` does. Variations abound.

EDIT: Found the proper duplicate. Will mark above.

Comment: Then why not mark this as a duplicate ?

Comment: Because the duplicates do it the hard way, instead of using objcopy.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: so contribute a better answer to the duplicate you choose.

Comment: Because this question is a spiderweb of posts. :-( But I think I found the duplicate with the top-voted correct answer: [Is there a Linux equivalent of Windows' "resource files"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997172/is-there-a-linux-equivalent-of-windows-resource-files)

Comment: You convinced yourself this is a dupe and closed my question.  

This isn't a windows question.  The windows resource file is not roughly analogous to this either. The .zip files are opened with fopen whereas a resource file is opened with a special Windows API.  I was hoping for some magic -- say a Fuse wrapper or a container technology that could hide the internal filesystem without changing the C code.

Comment: You did not mention any of this in your question. Reformulate your question to be more specific so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress files and share as self extracting archive, that is .exe format.

You can use 7-zip for that. [Use-7Zip-to-Create-Self-Extracting-excutables](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-7Zip-to-Create-Self-Extracting-excutables)