# Is it possible to extract resources from an ELF-format GUI programs?

Tags: linux, resources, extract

For Linux GUI applications, is it possible to extract embedded resources (image, icon, video ...) from them?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627004/embedding-binary-blobs-using-gcc-mingw), but this isn't usually done. More often, resources will be placed in `/usr/share/<application>` and accessed via normal filesystem functions.

Comment: the question ask "extract", not embed

Comment: @J-16: The accepted answer shows how to extract. But extracting is pointless without embedding regardless.

Comment: My understanding is, the OP have some proprietary program with some image embedded. Without knowing how they did it, he wants to extract them out.