# Issues embedding resources from a namespace (C++ & CMake)

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been using a technique for embedding resources (raw binary data) into compiled executables, using a combination of C, C++ and CMake.

The code/configuration I've used is very similar to what's available in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/cyrilcode/embed-resource), and I've even reproduced the issue with this particular sample.

Used as is, the resource embedding works great, but as soon as C++ namespacing is introduced, things start breaking left and right.

The issue seems to be that the C-style resources are by default using the global/anonymous namespace when called from within C++, but if they're called from a namespace inside C++, then that namespace gets prefixed to the resource, which results in undefined symbols.

So far I've tried all I can think of, including converting the original C-style code to C++ and using namespaces with it, which yields the same results.

More details on the specific calls/code can be seen in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/cyrilcode/embed-resource/issues/4).

Ps. I realize that there's hardly any code/context in this post, but I figured it would make more sense to link to the original topics/articles that go through this, instead of trying to explain it myself. Also, if it helps, this topic has also been discussed [here](https://beesbuzz.biz/blog/e/2014/07/31-embedding_binary_resources_with_cmake_and_c11.php) and even on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813271/embed-resources-eg-shader-code-images-into-executable-library-with-cmake).

Comment: I did a similar thing with shaders while teaching my son some techniques. 
Take a look in the `shaders` directory of this project.
https://github.com/AlexAndDad/dungeon

Comment: Do you expect everyone is familar with this tool ("embed-resource")? Looking into [its code](https://github.com/cyrilcode/embed-resource/blob/master/embedresource.cpp) I see simple `char sym_name[] = { bytes ... };` definition. Not sure how namespaces are related with it. And how CMake is related with all this problem? Yes, the tool uses CMake, but the problem isn't CMake-related, isn't it? Some code examples would definitely improve the question.

Comment: That's apparently not a C, but pure C++ problem.

Comment: @Olaf: From my understanding, the question is about "porting" `C` approach to the `C++`. Or even having approach suitable for both `C` and `C++`. So removed `C` tag was meaningful in some extent.

Comment: @Tsyvarev:; It is definitively not. There are no custom name spaces in C not are the required symbol features like name-mangling supported by C. Just using C ABI functions does not justify adding the C tag. Feel free to provide proof I'm wrong, provide the required information **in tthe question** and post a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf: This is not my question, so I can only *guess*. OK, lets wait clarification from the author.

Answer (score 2):

That `extern "C"` in C headers included from C++ code is exactly for calling C functions/objects from C++ without namespace (or better: for calling function/objects not by using C++ mangled name, but using a C name).
[This embded-rsource tool](https://github.com/cyrilcode/embed-resource/blob/master/embedresource.cpp) is cool, just add `extern "C"` in `LOAD_RESOURCE` like this:

```
 #define LOAD_RESOURCE(RESOURCE) ([]() {                      \
    extern "C" const char _resource_##RESOURCE[]; extern "C" const size_t _resource_##RESOURCE##_len;   \
    return Resource(_resource_##RESOURCE, _resource_##RESOURCE##_len);  \
})()
```

That way you instruct compiler, that `__resource##RESOURCE` is not a C++ symbol, but a C symbol compiled with a C compiler.

Comment: LÖet apart that unnecessarily using macros is even worse style in C++ than in C, it is not only about the symbols.

Comment: While this makes perfect sense, it unfortunately doesn't work, presumably due to using a macro? Error: expected unqualified-id