# How to use self ld, objcopy and ar in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I want use two version of static librares in my project. And I found an answer from 
[Restricting symbols in a Linux static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393980/restricting-symbols-in-a-linux-static-library).

But I don't know how to use cmake to run following commands:

```
ld -r obj1.o obj2.o ... objn.o -o static1.o
objcopy --localize-hidden static1.o static2.o
ar -rcs mylib.a static2.o
```

Comment: CMake has no builtin support for these commands. You need [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/add_custom_command.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) to call the command, like this:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "ld" "-r" "obj1.o" "obj2.o" ... WORKING_DIRECTORY "...")
```

or use `add_custom_command` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000564/cmake-embed-elf-into-executable)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```cmake
find_program(CMAKE_OBJCOPY objcopy)
```

or

```cmake
find_program(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objcopy)
```

where TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX is path to your custom toolchain (for example, if you build your solution for ARM, MIPS e.t.c.). See [example](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/master/eng/common/cross/android/arm/toolchain.cmake)

Then you may use command like this (use [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html)):

```cmake
    execute_process(COMMAND
      ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} --localize-hidden static1.o static2.o
      RESULT_VARIABLE objcopy_result
      ERROR_QUIET
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE objcopy_out)
```

or use [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)