# g++: compiling a huge static std::vector

Tags: c++, g++

I have generated a sorted list of about 117000 English words, which I have put into a `std::vector<std::string>` in a C++ header file, like so:

```
#ifndef WORDS_HPP
#define WORDS_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <string>

const std::vector<std::string> words{
    "a",
    "a\'s",
    "aa",
    "aa\'s",
    "aaa",

/* >100k lines omitted */

    "zyuganov",
    "zyuganov\'s",
    "zzz"
};

#endif
```

When including this monstrosity in a .cpp file and compiling the thing with g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, the compiler causes my system to run out of memory. I only have 4 GB, unfortunately.

I would like to have the vector compiled statically into my executable (toy project, FYI), but obviously I can't get it to work. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why not just read them in from a file?

Comment: @NathanOliver I would like to avoid external resources and just have the list compiled into the executable.

Comment: FWIW, using `char const* words [] = { ... };` works for me.

Comment: This should only take a few MB.  Check `ulimit`

Comment: Prefer not to place variables in header files.  Every source file that includes the header file will get a copy of the global variable.  This may violate the One Definition Rule (linker will complain about multiple copies).  Move to a source file.

Comment: I currently placed it in a source file, and already decided to use a static char * with a function to build the vector of strings at runtime. I am wondering whether there is a benefit to the initializer list, though, if I can get it to compile.

Comment: in how many source files is that header included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As R Shau says, this is a good solution:

```
char const* words [] = { ... };
```

It seems that when you initialize a std::string the compiler has to generate a call to the std::string constructor so the memory can be allocated on the heap.  It doesn't seem to generate any kind of loop ... you get a lot of assembly language out the back.

It does a lot better initializing a vector of integers, but still compared to the old C style array it's a lot of overhead.

There are also various tricks for embedding arbitrary data into your C/C++ program.  Some references:

- [Embedding binary blobs using gcc mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627004/embedding-binary-blobs-using-gcc-mingw)
- https://www.fourmilab.ch/xd/

Comment: Exactly what I needed +1. I currently use C style arrays and it works fine.