# How to Interface TCL and Shell scripts to C/C++ or any other languages?

Tags: c, api, tcl

I have few scripts developed in TCL and Shell

1. TCL scripts (project.tcl) is used for automation of project creation and handling the multiple project runs)
2. SHELL scripts (result.sh ) is created for result analysis Error handling with a set of commands using sed, awk and grep.

I want to create a single executable by embedding  these scripts into any high level language like C/C++ file. we know that TCL is a C library. What kind of  interface files APIs are useful for achieving this ?

Comment: Please don't sign you name at the end of questions or similar. See here for more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: If you rewrite the shell scripts in tcl, then you only have two languages to worry about (C and tcl)...

Comment: And if it's all in tcl, there are tools to create a binary that includes the tcl runtime and your scripts all in one: https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/bindist.html and https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Starpack

Answer (score 0):

1. TCL scripts are quite simple, as you can embed the TCL interpreter quite easy. (API-Reference: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+C+API)
2. You can simply embed them, extract them at runtime (to /tmp) and use `system(...)`, or you could try translating them to C:
   sed: https://github.com/lhoursquentin/sed-bin
   awk: awk2c
   grep: I didn't find some translator tool, but grep uses [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/), so you could use these.

To have them in the executable, you could make a .tar(.gz) file from those scripts, embed it into the binary ([Embedding binary blobs using gcc mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627004/13912132)), and load (and extract (with zlib, for example)) it at runtime, to a temporary directory.